# Number of subsets that meet the "spread out" condition

Tags: combinatorics

Let $S = \{ 1, 2,..., 12\}$, how many subsets of $S$ satisfy that the difference of any two number of the set is greater than $2$? Empty set and sets with only one element is counted in.

I am thinking of doing some partition and choosing numbers from each group. But it seems not to work. Any suggestion please? Thank you!

Comment: How many such subsets are there (you can list and count them) for $S=\{1,2,3\}$? For $S=\{1,2,3,4\}$? And so on. Do you see a pattern in the answers? Does this suggest anything?

Comment: @SteveKass Oh I see! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the form:
$$
1 + \binom{12-0}{1} + \binom{12-2}{2} + \binom{12-4}{3}+\binom{12-6}{4}
$$
Take $\binom{12-4}{3}$ as an example, we can think like this:

Assume we only have $8$ numbers, namely $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$, and we choose three numbers from them, such as $1,3,6$, we can always map it back to $1,3+2=5,6+2*2=10$, by adding the $2's$ back. This is one-to-one correspondence. Then we get the result in the end by adding them up.

Comment: This sort of problem lends itself to recursion.  Let $A_n$ be the answer for the set $\{1,2,\cdots, n\}$. (so you want $A_{12}$),  We remark that either $n$ is in our subset or it isn't.  If it is, then the rest of the subset must be an element of $A_{n-3}$.  If it isn't then the subset must be an element of $A_{n-1}$.  Thus $A_n=A_{n-1}+A_{n-3}$.

Comment: @lulu Yeah thanks so much. Your approach is much simpler...

Comment: @lulu yours should be an answer

Comment: @EdwardWang your answer doesnt make any sense to me. 1) where has the first equation come from and what do the terms represent? 2) How can we choose 4 elements form 6, with gaps of 2 from 1,2,3,4,5,6?

Answer (score 0):

Denote A[n] as the answer for {1,2,3,..,n}. Then A[n] = A[n-1] + (n-3). Each extra element appended will lend itself to (n-3) extra spread sets since dist(x,y) > 2